# Is a colon the best punctuation mark in the following case?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> None of the doctors could find the cause of the condition, or cure it: they
>   tried anti-acids, also anxiety drugs in case the problem was my
>   nerves.

I'm a little hesitant because the sentence that follows the colon is a full sentence. Is the colon appropiate in the sentence?

Comment: I downvoted this question for lack of research. There are many online websites that give pretty thorough punctuation guidance. If you provided some of that guidance in your question, and explain why you're still confused, I'd happily reverse my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The colon is correctly used in that sentence because it represents a new unit of information that is part of the whole and is in conjunction with it.